# Error: Header of CSV file is engaged decision tree calculation in scikit-learn Library

Tags: python, python-3.x, scikit-learn, decision-tree

I run the following code form creating decision tree by scikit-learn library.

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
import os
from sklearn.tree import export_graphviz
import graphviz

#progress 1
path="/mnt/d/TestDecisionTree/datasets"
os.chdir(path)
os.getcwd()

#progress 2
dataset=np.loadtxt("internetlogit.csv", delimiter=",")
x=dataset[:,0:5]
y=dataset[:,5]

#progress 3
from sklearn.tree import DecisionTreeRegressor
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(x, y)
tree = DecisionTreeRegressor().fit(X_train,y_train)

#progress 4
print("Training set accuracy: {:.3f}".format(tree.score(X_train, y_train)))
print("Test set accuracy: {:.3f}".format(tree.score(X_test, y_test)))

#progress 5
dtree = tree.predict(x)
print(dtree)

#progress 6
percentageerror_tree=((y-dtree)/dtree)*100
percentageerror_tree

#progress 7
np.mean(percentageerror_tree)

#progress 8
export_graphviz(tree,out_file="result/tree.dot")

with open("result/tree.dot") as f:
    dot_graph = f.read()

graphviz.Source(dot_graph)
```

My sample data is the following dataset in internetlogit.csv file

```
age,gender,webpages,videohours,income,usage
36,0,32,0.061388889,6021,0
33,0,49,8.516666667,10239,1
46,1,22,0,1374,0
53,0,16,2.762222222,5376,0
27,1,30,0,1393,0
21,1,23,2.641111111,4866,0
42,0,30,0,1673,0
...
```

But I get this error in "progress 2".

```
ValueError: could not convert string to float: 'age'
```

This means the header of CSV file are engaged in decision tree calculation. But, it should not be like that. How can I solved the problem?

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0):

`pandas` would be the easiest drop-in fix, for example:

```py
import pandas as pd
from io import StringIO

csv_file = StringIO("""
age,gender,webpages,videohours,income,usage
36,0,32,0.061388889,6021,0
33,0,49,8.516666667,10239,1
46,1,22,0,1374,0
53,0,16,2.762222222,5376,0
27,1,30,0,1393,0
21,1,23,2.641111111,4866,0
42,0,30,0,1673,0
""")

df = pd.read_csv(csv_file)

y = df["usage"]
x = df.drop(["usage"], axis=1)

from sklearn.tree import DecisionTreeRegressor
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(x, y)
tree = DecisionTreeRegressor().fit(X_train,y_train)
tree.fit(X_train, y_train)
print(tree)
```

The `ValueError` is raised on line 13 of the posted code since the column names cannot be interpreted as strings.

If you don't want to use pandas, you could also pass `skiprows` to `np.loadtxt`:

```py
dataset = np.loadtxt(csv_file, delimiter=",", skiprows=2)
x = dataset[:,0:5]
y = dataset[:,5]
```